# What does the following mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

Does the sentence **Reduced nuclear charge is called Effective nuclear charge**  mean

> 1. The portion(or amount) of nuclear charge that is reduced.  OR
> 2. The result( remaining amount) after some portion of the nuclear charge is reduced.

The whole sentence of which the above is a part is:

> There is a reduction in the nuclear charge due to screening effect, reduced nuclear charge is called Effective nuclear charge.

Comment: *The company will pay **reduced wages** next week*. In that context, obviously the highlighted noun phrase means *the wages **remaining** after reduction*. But in a context like [*the **reduced workers' compensation benefit** cannot be less than the supplementary minimum benefit,*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+reduced+workers+compensation%22) it's equally obvious that the highlighted noun phrase refers to *the workers **removed** from the workforce*. In other words, the actual ***syntax*** doesn't fix the interpretation. You have to use ***context + common sense***.

Comment: Thank you very much @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is talking about the remaining amount (i.e., your no.2).

[Reduced:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/reduced)

> less than before or less than usual
>
> ***reduced costs/hours/rates** The industry's workers have been subjected to **reduced hours** and the potential for layoffs.*

("reduced hours" here is equal to total hours less number of hours not available anymore)

If the intended meaning was "the portion (or amount) of nuclear charge that is reduced" (your no. 1) then it would say something like this:

> The amount of *reduction* in the nuclear charge is called ...

Or

> The amount by which the nuclear charge is reduced is called ...

Comment: Thank you so much @AIQ